# Python : How to trigger API with proxy enabled (proxy with yubi key as password)

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

I have an API that works with proxy enabled.

When hit through postman by enabling proxy, it works fine. In the proxy section, i provide yubi key as password.
[image: Postman proxy settings]

Now, I am trying to call this API in Python using requests module. I tried to set up proxy as **protocol://username:pwd@proxy:8080** with pwd as yubi key when calling the api, but i am facing the following error:

> InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'XXX'

post request:

```
requests.post(url=host + path, json=body, proxies=proxyDict, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(get_token)})
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can disable the error by using :

```py
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added **verify** param as **False** in the post call and it worked.

```
requests.post(url=host + path, proxies=proxyDict, json=body, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(get_token())}, verify=verify_ssl)
```